# How to create a translations library of Flash symbols for action script from an XML file?

Tags: flash, actionscript, localization, symbols

I have a list of 700 words that I would like to convert to symbols in Flash for a flash card game.  I'm trying to make a game where a random symbol from a slice of the array of symbols will come into game play until the user performs an action.

Basically, I'm wondering how I can create an arrayed/indexed library of symbols from a dictionary, for a downloadable Flash game.  Does anyone know how I could start to script this?  Also, if I want to pair a 'word symbol' with its translation, do I need to use a database?  Obviously, because it's a flash-card type game I'm working on, the translated symbol is just as valuable as the original-language symbol.

Comment: you can have a csv file or URLVariables String name-value pairs you can use or use xml (e.g. <game><item name="A" symbol="LetterA"/></game> )

Comment: Rather than creating 700 symbols, it would make more sense to use a symbol with a dynamic TextField that gets set to a word from the XML. The list of words is the data for your game/application.

Comment: @LarsBlåsjö, Could you describe how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking forward Lars's comment,

You first create a generic flashcard symbol. This should have a dynamic textfield in it.
Then, on loading the swf, you load the xml (or the csv) containing the words, parse it and load the words into an array. Next, you generate a random number and select that index of the array to display in the textfield.

Code and screenshots coming soon... :)

**EDIT**

[image: Creating the symbol]

The source files are [here](http://www.uploads.sc/download.php?file=d9f9bb4a45a636c8fb969f0f8ab4efb8)

**EDIT 2**

Do you know how to parse XML?
I have written this class which I use for converting an XML into an Object. You can get the swc from [here](http://www.uploads.sc/download.php?file=8b7704700e82d2d2fb709c27634703f3)

You just need to read in the xml file, and then run

```
var obj:Object=XMLUtilities.XMLStringToObject(string)
```

This will return an object of the xml
For example, suppose your xml is

```
<words>
    <x id="1"><english>ball</english><spanish>pelota</spanish></x>
    <x id="2"><english>cat</english><spanish>gato</spanish></x>
</words>
```

The value of `obj` will be

obj=>words=>x:Array
So you can access each `x` tag as

```
obj.words.x[index]
```

and, then you have x.id=1; x.english="ball"; x.spanish="pelota" and so on.

So, in that case, the word selection code would be a little different. I've uploaded all files [here](http://www.uploads.sc/download.php?file=d7c935a6d26bd22edb3d17f1441b771f)

Comment: Pranav, are you using some kind of program to generate the dynamic textfield within the symbol?  Also, thanks for stepping up to this question.  You rock.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08, Flash CS5 Professional is what I am using

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 I have added a screenshot and a link to the source. Check it out. You will need Flash CS5 to open the source. This example was just a quick fix to show you how to do it. Play with it, check out the FlashCard symbol in the library, have fun. Best of luck

Comment: Sorry to bother, but would you happen to have a solution for pairing with a translation (for example, on-click goto translation)?  Actually, maybe I can just use some kind of loop

Comment: Well, using XML I have: `<x id="1"><english>ball</english><spanish>pelota</spanish></x><x id="2"><english>cat</english><spanish>gato</spanish></x>`, for example.  With 700 words, though, matching each word to its translated version, again, manually, is very time consuming.  If there's no simple solution, though, I can find a way to script it.

Comment: Added xml parsing to the answer

Comment: whoa, that xml parsing took some time :P Added it now, check it out

Comment: AHAH!!!!  Here we go!  You know what, I just needed to figure out how to open up the "Actions" window.  Now I can view the code, I guess.  Tough to figure out, but I think I can get it from here, eventually.  Thank you, Pranav.  You rock.

Comment: It only takes the first word in the array.  I can definitely figure out how to randomize from the code view, though.  This is tight.  You rock.

Comment: There are compile errors, also: `Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 45 1120: Access of undefined property XMLUtilities.`;----  
`Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 7 1172: Definition com.flexutilities.xml:XMLUtilities could not be found.`;----

`Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 7 1172: Definition com.flexutilities.xml:XMLUtilities could not be found.`

Comment: I resolved it by changing the location of the swc file in Properties>Action Script (tool icon)>Library Path.  I'm so-so at parsing XML files with domdoc.  I'll try to inspect the class, somehow.  I hope I can figure it out. :)

Comment: I don't think you will be able to see the code for the swf, but it's pretty straightforward. I can't find the code myself because my filesystem has recently received a major overhaul. Anyway, I remember that the `XMLUtilities.XMLStringToObject` uses only library functions of AS3, and there is not too much extra logic. I have been using this class for quite some time because it converts all my xmls to easily accessible Objects

Comment: Happy to have been of help, all the best!! :)

Comment: Oh, I was actually hoping only to see the code for the swc file.  I'm not sure how to bring it up.

Comment: I found out that .swc files are just .zip files renamed for Flash.  Apparently, they only contain .swf files, and they cannot be inspect.

Comment: Found the file, here y'are: http://www.uploads.sc/download.php?file=72f74d2cbafc0ef847b8cdefd8b2f112

Comment: Man, you're the best.  Now I can even figure out how the XML parsing starts.  Thank you, so much.

Comment: I found out that it's this line: `function parseCSV(s:String):void {
        var a:Array=s.split(",");
        for (var i:int=0; i<a.length; i++) {
                wordsArray.push(a[i]);
        }` that is causing the issue.  Because it only works on csv's, the array is never filled.  I'm still working on a bugfix.  Maybe something like this: `for(var i:int = 0; i < xml.word.length; i++){  var o:Object = xml.word[i].node;  items.push(item);}`